# How to make a URL in my RestService?

Tags: java, rest, url, jax-rs

I am trying to make RestService in which I want to make my URL call like this -

```
http://localhost/pat/v1/clients/12345/data/flag
```

I will pass `clientId` in the url as `12345` and I will also pass JSON document to my RESTService by posting it through POSTMAN. So I need to extract clientId which is 12345 and JSON document which I am posting to my REST Service.

I have my below code which makes the URL like this as of now - `http://localhost/pat/consumer` and then whatever JSON I am posting to my Service, I am extracting it through InputStream.

```
@Path("/pat")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @POST
    @Path("consumer")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response crunchREST(InputStream incomingData) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingData));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
        }
        System.out.println("Data Received: " + sb.toString());
    }

}
```

I recently started with RestService. How can I make the above URL call in my RestService? And extract the `clientId` in the method about and also JSON as well which I am posting by using POSTMAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `id` is the only varying part in your URL so use it as a PathParam.

Here you go:

```
@Path("/v1/clients/{id}/data/flag")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response crunchREST(InputStream incomingData,@PathParam("id") Integer id)
```